# isHappy.js allowing ajax call when not valid

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm throwing this up in hope that someone might spot a mistake because I've gone over this way to many times now. It was working fine for about ten minutes but then just broke.

I have a codeigniter website with a very simple contact form with 3 fields. I'm using isHappy.js to validate the form and then send off to the server. isHappy.js should stop the AJAX function until the form has validated but this parts not happening. If I click the submit button without filling out the form the validation errors flash up but then the ajax call is made and the form is submit.

### Heres the Javascript:

```
 $(function() { 

 $('#contact-form').isHappy({
   fields: {

     '#email': {
       required: true,
       message: 'How can I reach you sans email??'
     },
     '#subject': {
       required: true,
       message: 'Can you give me a clue to what you inquiring about please'
     },
     '#body': {
       required: true,
       message: 'More details please....'
     }
   }
});

 $('#contact-form').bind('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var query_params = $('#contact-form').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',       
                    url: 'http://website.dev:8080/contact/email/ajax',
                    data: query_params,
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(string){
                        $('#contact-form').fadeOut('medium', function() {
                                $('#linkedin').after("<div style=\"clear:both;\" /><div id=\"contact-complete\" stlye=\"width:100%;height:200px;\"><h1>"+string+"</h1></div>").fadeIn('medium');        
                        });                                                             
                    }

                });
    });     
});
```

### And the HTML:

```
<form action="http://website.dev:8080/contact/email" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="contact-form">        
<div class="contact-input">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" value="" />
</div>
<div class="contact-input">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="" />
</div>
<div class="contact-textarea">
    <textarea rows="10" placeholder="How can I help you?" name="body" id="body"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="contact-click" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [happy.js docs](http://happyjs.com/), If validation fails two things happen:

1. The field will get an `unhappy` class.
2. The field will get a `<span>` right before it, in the DOM with a class of `unhappyMessage` and an id of whatever the field's id is plus `_unhappy`.

This is purely presentational. You'll have to check that the form does not contain any inputs with `unhappy` classes before your AJAX call.

```
var is_unhappy = false;
$('#contact-form div :input').each( function(i) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('unhappy') ) {
        is_unhappy = true;
        return false;
    }
});
if(!is_unhappy){
    //do ajax.
}
```

Comment: Too easy thanks! I adjusted your script to look if a span exists in the form. The classes isHappy.js applies are to the spans not the inputs so it winds up being much simpler as I don't have any other spans in the form. Cheers!#

Comment: Also note that there is a `unHappy` option to add a callback if the form does not validate so 3. happy.js calls the callback defined in the `unHappy` property.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell without the HTML but what type of input are you using?  It looks like you are using an input tag of type submit, you could just change it to an input tag of type button and bind to click -- then your problems should go away.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, I tried your idea but unfortunately no luck. I just uploaded the HTML if that helps. Cheers.