# AJAX Form still submitting (in Safari) with Happy.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, happy.js

HTML5 validation isn't working in Safari so I'm using Happy.js.
My form is still submitting via ajax in Safari though with the code below (here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm0qk5j6/1/)).

How can I validate #email-input before sending the form with ajax?

The code below is checking `if ($(this).hasClass('unhappy'))` then don't submit form, if it doesn't have class `unhappy` then submit form. But I guess the problem is that it doesn't have class `unhappy` from the beginning.
 *used from this reference: [isHappy.js allowing ajax call when not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609862/ishappy-js-allowing-ajax-call-when-not-valid)*

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxEmailForm() {
        $(".sendingEmailLink, .sentEmailLink").hide();
        $('#email-form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formserialize = $(this).serialize();
            var submitButton = $('#submitEmailForm');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://formkeep.com/f/MYID',
                accept: {
                    javascript: 'application/javascript'
                },
                data: formserialize,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".sendEmailLink").hide();
                    $('.sendingEmailLink').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $(".sendingEmailLink").hide();
                },
                success: function(d) {
                    $('.sentEmailLink').show();
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('.notification-e--phone').slideDown("medium", function() {});
                },
            }).done(function(data) {
                submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
        });
    };
    $('#email-form').isHappy({
        fields: {
            '#email-input': {
                required: true,
                test: happy.email,
                message: 'Please enter your full email address.',
                errorTarget: '.email-input-error'
            }
        }
    });
    var is_unhappy = false;
    $('#email-form div :input').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('unhappy')) {
            is_unhappy = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!is_unhappy) {
        ajaxEmailForm();
    };
  });
```